# Java Data Structure Question with seting up Object instead of a special Object Like Integer, Double, String, ect

Tags: java

I have a few questions about implementing data structures LinkList, ArrayList, and many other linear and nonlinear data structures.

On the job do you call most of them Objects like `LinkList<Object or Name> name = new LinkList<>();`

I ask cuz majority of the time it seems practical to just state `Object` inside an ArrayList or LinkList so you don't get a Data type error. then when pulling the data you call the data type when **unboxing**

What is your experience? also, do you use imported data types or do you create them from scratch like creating your own LinkedList with nodes for example

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

LinkedList<Object> ll = new LinkedList<>();
```

### or

```
public class LinkedList {
    Node head;
    public void append(Object data) {
        if(head == null) {
            head = new Node(data);
            return;
        }
        Node current = head;
        while(current.next!=null)
        {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next=new Node(data);
    }
    public void prepend(Object data) {
        Node newHead = new Node(data);
        newHead.next = head;
        head = newHead;
    }
}
class Node{
    Node next;
    Object data;
    public Node(Object data) {      
        this.data = data;
    }   
}
```

normally I have int for data type but I change it to Object because it can take more values instead of int. with this code changing the int to Object better? I figured Java devs would give me these insights on this Id appreciate it.

Comment: Hey! You need to check out what [generics](https://www.journaldev.com/1663/java-generics-example-method-class-interface) in Java are. You should use classes that already exist *except* when you know you can implement something more efficient or better for *your* use case. For usual tasks you can count on Java's standard collections to work as well as it can get.

Comment: Why would you *ever* want to write your own LinkedList implementation, when somebody else has already done the work for you? Well, aside from doing it for practice? It is simply a waste of time.

Comment: Also, you should know what kind of things go into your list, and use an appropriate data type, rather than <Object> or <?>. Those TypeErrors aren't just for fun - they are a tool to keep you from making stupid errors like accidentally mixing up data types inside a list of objects and then getting confusing runtime errors.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Tasch! I was only asking cause I'm always reviewing my data structures and learning how to tackle coding challenges and a lot of lectures online just go int how to implement your own linkedlist for example and I wasn't sure it they are going over the concepts of how for example a linkedlist works or that also in the industry uses more linkedlist from scratch. Cuz I was thinking the same thing that whey would I need to build my own linklist when I can just import one.

Comment: Thanks akuzminykh Ill take a look at generics again.

Comment: I usually use the List interface, rather than any concrete ArrayList or LinkedList class.  I also usually create a custom class for the List.  For example, List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Thanks, Gilbert I appreciate your input